# How can i make a 'view_count' in django-rest-framework?

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

Thank you all the time. I will ask. 
(I'm sorry for not good at English very well)

I'm using react as a front end, so I just started the Django rest framework.

but The django-rest-framework is confusing for me, so I ask.

As a simple example, I want to automatically increment view_count when I click show page in crud.

What function should I write in app_name/api/views.py ?

here is my code ..

```py
# notice/models.py

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Notice(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
  description = models.TextField()
  view_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

```py
# notice/api/views.py

from rest_framework import viewsets
from notice.models import Notice
from .serializers import NoticeSerializer
from django.http import JsonResponse

class NoticeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  serializer_class = NoticeSerializer
  queryset = Notice.objects.order_by('title')
```

```py
# notice/api/serializers.py

from rest_framework import serializers
from notice.models import Notice

class NoticeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Notice
    fields = ('id','title','description','view_count')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would add the increment in the `NoticeViewSet.retrieve()` method.  This is the view method called when you retrieve a single object, so it makes sense.  You could also add this to the `list` view method, but depending on the size of the queryset it could get quite slow.

```
class NoticeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = NoticeSerializer
    queryset=Notice.objects.order_by('title')

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = self.get_object()
        obj.view_count = obj.view_count + 1
        obj.save(update_fields=("view_count", ))
        return super().retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

If you want to also count views when Notices are listed then use this class:

```
class NoticeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = NoticeSerializer
    queryset=Notice.objects.order_by('title')

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = self.get_object()
        obj.view_count = obj.view_count + 1
        obj.save(update_fields=("view_count", ))
        return super().retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # You could also increment the view count if people see the `Notice` in a listing.
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        for obj in queryset:
            obj.view_count = obj.view_count + 1
            obj.save(update_fields=("view_count", ))
        return super().list(request, *args, **kwargs
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.

Using the above code, view_count will work, but if I click on a single notice(ex:notice/1), all notices view_count count...

What should I do in this case?

Comment: Are you sure you're hitting the detail endpoint?  The code is fairly simple, unless you're requesting the list view it should only increment a single `Notice`.

Comment: Yes, it is. Could you give me the code?
I do not have any lecture about this, so please let me know the sample code and I would like to study it by applying it.

If possible, I would appreciate your favor.

Comment: The code I was referring to was the `NoticeViewSet` in my answer, there are two actions, `retrieve` and `list`.  I've separated the class into two different types, one that implements `retrieve` and another that implements `retrieve` and `list`, try the `retrieve` only implementation and you should be alright.