# How to add view count everytime endpoint get request accessed

Tags: python, django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm building a REST API with Django rest framework.

One of the models :

```
class Feed(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    content = models.TextField()
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_profile_image_filepath, default='uploads/feed/index.jpg', blank=True)
    imgpath = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank=True, default=timestr)
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    view = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I want the feed view added when the user accessed the endpoint.

views.py

```
class FeedDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Feed.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FeedSerializer
```

urls.py

```
path('feeds/<int:pk>/', FeedDetail.as_view()),
```

Comment: Please check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56229309/8523960.

Answer (score 0):

Receive the id from payload
Use get method to filter the data from table
Increase the view count by updating the existing value of view using the get object and save the get object

Comment: can you be more elaborate?